# Auth()->user() or Auth::user() return wrong User Data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing a unique issue, There are only 3 user data in my database John, Cindy & Carla, I Login using the username john, but I get Auth data of Carla, it's supposed to be Auth data of john.

here is my **Login function** inside `LoginController.php`

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    $credentials = ['user_id' => \Arr::get('user_id','', $request->input('user_id')),                  
        'password' => \Arr::get('password','', $request->input('user_password'))
    ]; 

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        return  redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return back()->withInput($request->except('password'))->withErrors(['Username atau Password Wrong! ']);
}
```

Here is my **User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    protected $table = "m_user";
    protected $primaryKey = "user_id";

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->hash_password;
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'nama', 'user_password','hash_password','role', 'company','is_active','created_by','created_at','updated_by','updated_at'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

> the thing is when i put **`dd(Auth()->user())`** after the
> `Auth::attempt()` i get **John User data** which is **correct**, but if i `dd(Auth()->user())` in `another Controller` in my Application, i get **Carla Auth data**. why?

> FYI: Carla is the first row data in my User Table.

```
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
   dd(auth()->user()); <---- here, i get John Auth Data
   return  redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

> try to dd in another Controller. but get Carla Auth Data.

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {
    public function overview() {
        dd(auth()->user()); <---- i get Carla Auth Data, it's supposed to John Auth data.
    }
}
```

> the question is that why `Auth::user() or auth()->user()` not return the login user's data in another Controller?

Comment: session could be an issue

Comment: Are you logging out before login with new user?

Comment: yes, i am logging out and using incognito browser. what am i missing ? @DhairyaLakhera

Answer (score 0):

You could write an if statement inside `if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){}` to check whether it is the desirable user or not. 
As a result you can debug it and make sure this problem really exists because it sounds really weird